# how to achieve inside curve of barchart using recharts

Tags: reactjs, graph, recharts

**Expected Output**
[image]

I want to achieve similar charts using [recharts](https://recharts.org/en-US/) library
is there any thing that i can achieve similar charts?

**here is my snippet**

```
          <BarChart
              data={[
                {
                  "value1": 200,
                  "value2": 300,
                  type: '1',
                },
                ...
              ]}
            layout="vertical" >
                     <CartesianGrid
              vertical={true}
              horizontal={false}
              stroke="#D2E7FB"
              fillOpacity={0}
            />
              <XAxis type="number" />
              <YAxis width={80} type="category" dataKey="type" offset={10} />
              
              <Tooltip />

              <Bar
                radius={[0, 0, 0, 0]}
                dataKey="value1"
                fill="#54C6F0"
                stackId="a"
              />
              <Bar
               stackId="a"
                radius={[10, 10, 10, 10]}
              
                dataKey="value2"
                fill="#F7B315"
              />
            </BarChart>
```

**CURRENT OUTPUT**

[image]

anything that i am missing can you help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample in React without recharts:

```js
const data = [
  {
    value1: 200,
    value2: 300,
  },
  {
    value1: 120,
    value2: 250,
  },
  {
    value1: 100,
    value2: 200,
  },
];

const SPACING = 3;
const firstPath = value1 => `M 0,-10 H ${value1} A 10,10 1 1 1 ${value1},10 H 0 Z`; 
const secondPath = (value1, value2) => `M ${value1 + SPACING},-10 H ${value2} A 10,10 1 1 1 ${value2},10 H ${value1 + SPACING} A 10,10 0 0 0 ${value1 + SPACING},-10 Z`; 



const GraphItem = ({data, index}) => {
    const {value1, value2} = data;
    return (
    <g transform={`translate(10, ${index * 50 + 20})`}>
      <path d={firstPath(value1)} fill="#F7B315" />
      <path d={secondPath(value1, value2)} fill="#54C6F0" />
    </g>
  );
}

const Graph = ({data}) => {
    return (
    <svg width="400" height="170">
    {data.map((item, index) => 
        <GraphItem data={item} index={index} key={index} />)
    }
    </svg>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Graph data={data} />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
</div>
```

Comment: perfect thank you so much @Michael Rovinsky

Comment: https://recharts.org/en-US/examples/CustomShapeBarChart

Comment: Thank you for your input. However, the question explicitly seeks a solution using Recharts, and the provided response seems to use a different library. For clarity, the question is specifically looking for Recharts-specific insights or examples to achieve the desired inside curve for bar charts. If anyone has Recharts expertise and can provide guidance, your input would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!